# How to get variable within react button element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im iterating with .map over react button elements and im trying to get time and disabled values from inside the button element.

```
const dates = days.map(product =>
   <div className='col-sm'>
     <div className='col-md'>
         <Button time={"8"} disabled={false}>8:00 AM</Button>
         <Button time={"9"} disabled={false}>9:00 AM</Button>
         <Button time={"10"} disabled={false}>10:00 AM</Button>
     </div>
   </div>
);
```

I tried to figure this out and this is the only way I got time and disabled within the elements.

```
dates.forEach(div => 
     div.props.children[1].props.children[1].props.time
     div.props.children[1].props.children[0].props.disabled
)
```

Is there easier way to get time string and disabled boolean values?

Comment: Where are you trying to _get_ them? Within the `<Button>` component or in the parent? And for what purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product will have to store all of the data and then you should be able to access it trough the first parameter of map.

```
export default function App() {
  const product = [
    { time: "8:00 AM", disabled: false },
    { time: "9:00 AM", disabled: false },
    { time: "10:00 AM", disabled: false },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {product.map((data) => (
        <button disabled={data.disabled}>{data.time}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This might work